# Create SVG Marker with circle and path inside

Tags: svg, marker

I got some graph in my app (using d3.js library), and I want to add special marker , that looks like circle and an arrow inside of it (in short: arrow with circular and colored background) .

I read that I cant really do a path between of my circle tag, 
so how can I handle this issue ?

```
<defs>
    <marker id="circle1" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="8" refX="5" refY="5">
        <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="3"></circle>
    </marker>
</defs>
```

What I need :

[image]

Comment: Add a path as the sibling of the circle. Not sure I understand exactly what your issue is here.

Answer (score 4):

A marker can have more than one element inside it.

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <marker id="circle1" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="8"
            refX="5" refY="5" orient="auto">
      <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="3" fill="black"/>
      <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="2" fill="white"/>
      <path d="M 4,3.5 L 6.5,5 L 4,6.5 Z" fill="black"/>
    </marker>
  </defs>
  
  <line x1="50" y1="120" x2="250" y2="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"
        marker-end="url(#circle1)" />
</svg>
```